# Does it ever make sense to create child actors inside a Receive-method in AKKA?

Tags: .net, akka, akka.net, actor-model

Let us assume I need to delegate some sub-process to a child actor. I could create the child actor during initialization of the actor (called PreStart in AKKA.NET). If I need multiple child actors to run in parallel I can use AKKA routers. I consider this the recommended approach.

However, I could also create the child actor inside the Receive-method and let the reference to the IActorRef instance have local scope of the Receive-method. Would this approach ever make sense? Would it provide any advantages over the case described above?

Answer (score 3):

It makes perfect sense to create child actors in a message handler, especially when you can't create them a priori because you create them dynamically depending on incoming data.

A prime example of this is the [Child Per Entity pattern](https://petabridge.com/blog/top-akkadotnet-design-patterns/), where you create an actor for each entity id. Thus if you receive a message with a new id you haven't received before, you will need to spin up a new child actor.

You can see [how the web crawler sample does this](https://github.com/petabridge/akkadotnet-code-samples/blob/master/Cluster.WebCrawler%2Fsrc%2FWebCrawler.Service%2FActors%2FApiMaster.cs). While the first temptation would be to maintain a dictionary of id to child actor, it turns out that this is not even necessary. As the web crawler sample does, you can check the actor's `Children` to determine whether it has that child already or not.

When you create child actors dynamically, you may want to give them a `ReceiveTimeout` to ensure that they don't leak memory by living forever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example,  if each message that is received begins some stateful process you would create child actors to handle this process. These child actors might need to respond to other messages from other actors. There might then be a final message that tells the process to finish. You can pass around an IActorRef as part of a message so the concept of local-scope doesn't necessarily apply.

Comment: Ok I see. I read somewhere that best practice advocates to avoid stateful actors if at all possible and instead put all state in the messages being passed around. It is all about the protocol, as they say. Do you agree with this argument? Or do you often end up using stateful child actors?

Comment: Have a read of https://petabridge.com/blog/stateful-web-applications where they discuss stateful actors

Answer (score 1):

Another example where actors are created dynamically are Extra and Cameo patterns described [here](http://www.slideshare.net/shinolajla/effective-akka-scalaio) and source code [here](https://github.com/jamie-allen/effective_akka/tree/master/src/main/scala/org/jamieallen/effectiveakka/pattern)

The basic idea of Cameo pattern is to front the actual workers (Cameos) with a responsive facade. It is different from Router because Facade is not on the response path, it hands all relevant context to Cameo and lets it complete the job and communicate the result directly to the sender (of the original job).

Extra pattern is the same but with anonymous actor. Cameo actor is better because it provides better logs (with readable actor names) and structures the code a bit better. Also it's more difficult to close over the state of the facade actor.

Bottom line: creating actors per request allows you to better insulate units of work, keeps "entry point" actors less busy and provides better scoped logs (which could be extremely important to understand distributed system behavior).

Comment: Thank you @Tim. I will look up these patterns.